# Any general aviation terminals have jet bridges?

Tags: general-aviation

Has anyone seen a FBO or general aviation terminal with a loading bridge for passengers? I remember flying into PHL on a commercial flight landing at Terminal F and they had ground level loading bridges, so they do exist, just not sure if they use them for private aircraft or charter airlines.

Comment: Near as I know, the answer is no. But who knows. It’ll be interesting to see what people come up with in the comments.

Comment: I have on another forum website  made aware of at least two in the United States, seems they are rare, however do exist. One is at Topeka Regional Airport the other at Oakland International (PTK) in Waterford, MI.

Comment: What is a "ground level loading bridge"?  By definition a bridge would normally span two points that are above ground level...

Comment: Philadelphia International has them in Terminal F you can depart a regional jet or other small commercial airliners and the terminal end of the bridge is at ground level connected to the terminal.